# When can we take the integral limit from and to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 115 he writes this:

[image]

I didn't understand why $\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}\ge 0$ implies this limit is true. What are the conditions to allow us to take this limit?

Comment: If you are dealing with Riemann Integral, the above equality is just the definition of an improper integral. However, if you are dealing with Lebesgue integral, this is the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: @Rubertos ok, but why does this definition make sense? thank you for your comment.

Comment: I don't get your question. Are you asking whether the right hand side limit exists? It does exist in $[0,\infty]$ since it is monotonically increasing.

Comment: @Rubertos exactly!